# Python split at tag regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split these lines:

```
<label>Olympic Games</label>
<title>Next stop</title>
```

Into:

```
["<label>", "Olympic Games", "</label>"]
["<title>", "Next stop", "</title>"]
```

In Python I can use regular expressions but what I've made doesn't do anything:

```
line.split("<\*>")
```

Comment: Is this xml?  Why not use an xml parser?

Comment: In addition to @StevenRumbalski, obligatory notice that this is a bad idea because regexes lack sufficient power to accurately interpret context-free grammars (e.g. XML, HTML, balanced parens). You have been Warned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lookarounds and a capture group to keep the text after splitting:

```
re.split(r'(?<=>)(.+?)(?=<)', '<label>Olympic Games</label>')
```

Comment: It is better to use lookarounds?, I have tried your regex in regexpal but is neither supported on javascript or PCRE.

Comment: @algui91 This doesn't work in JS because it uses a lookbehind, but it should work in PCRE. Anyway, it's hard to say if it's "better", that'll depend on the exact text OP will use it on. There won't be significant difference in speed or memory consumption, but it's possible that your pattern will match strings that my pattern won't, or the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

This regex works for me:

```
<(label|title)>([^<]*)</(label|title)>
```

or, as *cwallenpoole* suggested:

```
<(label|title)>([^<]*)</(\1)>
```

[image]

I've used http://www.regexpal.com/

I have used three capturing groups, if you don't need them, simply remove the `()`

What is wrong about your regex `<\*>` is that is matching only one thing: `<*>`. You have scaped `*` using `\*`, so what you are saying is:

- Match any text with `<`, then a `*` and then a `>`.

Comment: `<(label|title)>([^<]*)</(\1)>` is better

Comment: @cwallenpoole You are right, it is more elegant. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Data:

```
line = """<label>Olympic Games</label>
<title>Next stop</title>"""
```

With look-ahead / look-behind assertions with `re.findall`:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("(<.*(?<=>))(.*)((?=</)[^>]*>)")
print re.findall(pattern, line)
# [('<label>', 'Olympic Games', '</label>'), ('<title>', 'Next stop', '</title>')]
```

Without look-ahead / look-behind assertions, just by capturing groups, with `re.findall`:

```
pattern = re.compile("(<[^>]*>)(.*)(</[^>]*>)")
print re.findall(pattern, line)
# [('<label>', 'Olympic Games', '</label>'), ('<title>', 'Next stop', '</title>')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind punctuation, here is a quick non-regex alternative using `itertools.groupby`.

**Code**

```
import itertools as it


def split_at(iterable, pred, keep_delimter=False):
    """Return an iterable split by a delimiter."""
    if keep_delimter:
        return [list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(iterable, pred)]
    return [list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(iterable, pred) if k]
```

**Demo**

```
>>> words = "Lorem ipsum ..., consectetur ... elit, sed do eiusmod ...".split(" ")
>>> pred = lambda x: "elit" in x
>>> split_at(words, pred, True)
[['Lorem', 'ipsum', '...,', 'consectetur', '...'],
 ['elit,'],
 ['sed', 'do', 'eiusmod', '...']]

>>> words = "Lorem ipsum ..., consectetur ... elit, sed do eiusmod ...".split(" ")
>>> pred = lambda x: "consect" in x
>>> split_at(words, pred, True)
[['Lorem', 'ipsum', '...,'],
 ['consectetur'],
 ['...', 'elit,', 'sed', 'do', 'eiusmod', '...']]
```