# Scraping the portion of HTML code (not text) using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to use Selenium to scrape a portion of HTML code (not all) from a complete web page for use in my current project. I do not want the inner text of the HTML, but the actual code and store it in an external text file or a new HTML file.

[image]

Limitation: I cannot use any other library because the website is dynamic and rich in J.S only Selenium will work.

Comment: Which portion of `HTML code` are you looking for?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors why you should not post errors or code as screenshots.

Comment: it is a sample code it is not actual code,just want people to grab the idea.

Comment: @DebanjanB you can check the sample code/

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad Can you update the question with text based _HTML_ and the exact block of _HTML_ you are trying to _scrap_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its possible to extract the selected html with selenium. Either you can extract complete html or you will have to extract each element one by one:

to extract whole header tag (including header) using outerHTML:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("header cf")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

to extract everything inside nav(including nav):

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Comment: But how can i put the limit to the scraping, i mean how can i define the endpoint?

Comment: you don't define end point, you only define starting point and outerHTML will return the HTML of the element itself plus all the children elements

Comment: another thing you can do is to split the html after scrapping to get the required portion, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422360/python-split-at-tag-regex